# Passing a python variable to c shell script through Batch file in windows

Tags: python, windows, shell, batch-file, csh

I want to pass the python variable to c shell script using Batch file. Let me explain in detail, I have a c shell script which I am running in the windows operating system. I am using Cygwin to run the shell script as I am calling the shell script from a batch file and that batch file is being called from a python script.

```
e.g.
here is my python script:

from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("testbatch.bat", cwd=r"C:\cygwin64\home\nprak")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate() 

Here is my batch file (testbatch.bat):
#This will call the c shell script
C:\cygwin64\bin\tcsh ./testbatch.csh
Pause

Here is my C shell script:
# I just want to print a variable(for demo purpose)
set test_var = 4
echo $test_var
```

Now I want to pass the python variable to my C shell script. I do know to pass the python variable to shell script directly in the Linux but here since I am using windows so I have to use the batch file. Is there any way we can pass the python variable to c shell script in the case mentioned above.

Any suggestion comments is appreciated.

Comment: You can just use `Popen(['C:/cygwin64/bin/tcsh', './testbatch.csh', my_argument])`? Why use the `.bat` file at all?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker you are correct, I don't need to use the batch file at all but then how will I pass the multiple arguments into the shell script. I mean can you please show an example by passing 1 or 2 variables. In place of my arguements shall I just put the variables I need to pass to shell script.

Comment: You can just add arguments to the list you pass in `Popen`:  `Popen(['C:/cygwin64/bin/tcsh', './testbatch.csh', my_argument_1, my_argument_2])`, and in your csh script you just use `$argv[1]`, `$argv[2]`, etc...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted. ppl in this forum are just awesome